# How to apply requirement for Machine OU to SCCM Deployment Type

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm

I'm creating a script to deploy App-V applications into SCCM, and everything is working, other than setting requirements on the new deployment type. I need to apply 3 OUs.

So far I've worked out how to deserialize the SDMPackage XML, and have drilled down into an existing Deployment Type which has the values inside that I need. How would I go about setting a *new* deployment type to have this information?

I've tried following https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/9sfbul/updating_application_sdmpackagexml_example/ but I don't know what format is required for setting the OUs. Nothing I tried is accepted.

```bsh
AuthoringScopeId   : GLOBAL
LogicalName        : MACHINEOU
SettingDataType    : Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.ScalarDataType
SettingLogicalName : MachineOU_Setting_LogicalName
MethodType         : Value
PropertyPath       : 
SettingSourceType  : CIM
IsDirty            : False
ItemUniqueId       : GLOBAL/MACHINEOU
OperandDataType    : Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.ScalarDataType

ValueList              : {, , }
Values                 : {OU=UAT,OU=Desktops,OU=Physical,OU=Windows10,OU=Clients,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local, 
                         OU=UAT,OU=Laptops,OU=Physical,OU=Windows10,OU=Clients,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local, 
                         OU=UAT,OU=XenApp,OU=Virtual,OU=Windows10,OU=Clients,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local}
CultureInvariantValues : {OU=UAT,OU=Desktops,OU=Physical,OU=Windows10,OU=Clients,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local, 
                         OU=UAT,OU=Laptops,OU=Physical,OU=Windows10,OU=Clients,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local, 
                         OU=UAT,OU=XenApp,OU=Virtual,OU=Windows10,OU=Clients,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=rootdomain,DC=local}
ListValueType          : Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.VectorDataType
IsDirty                : False
OperandDataType        : Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.VectorDataType
```

Comment: I've recently and unsuccessfully tried to do this myself. I believe the syntax for the operands is "MachineOU_Setting_LogicalName/MACHINEOU" and the syntax for the DisplayName is "Organizational unit (OU) One of {OU=Computers,OU=ABCD,DC=location,DC=local}". I've reached out to MS about this, I'll post an answer once I've had a response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have figured that out. If not, maybe this can help:

```
  $ApplicationName = "your app name" 
  [Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject]$Application = Get-CMApplication -Name $ApplicationName
  $DeserializedApp =  [Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer]::DeserializeFromString($Application.SDMPackageXML, $true)

  # This will take expression for first deployment type and its first requirement, 
  # so if you have more deployment types with multiple requirements probably you want to add some filtering
  [Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.Expression]$Expression = 
  [Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.Expression]$DeserializedApp.DeploymentTypes[0].Requirements[0].Expression
  $OuValue = New-Object Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.DesiredConfigurationManagement.Expressions.OUValue -ArgumentList "here put your OU",$true 

  # MACHINE OU Expression consists of two operands, you want to add OU to second one
  $Expression.Operands[1].ValueList.Add($OuValue)

  # Now serialize back to string
  $Application =  [Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer]::Serialize($DeserializedApp)
  $Application.Put()
```